Unwanted border: PNG cutout of an image using GIMP, imported into Inkscape, exported as PDF, printed on paper
I have a very faint unwanted border when I print a PDF that has been exported from Inkscape.  I think this could be related to the background still showing something and is not fully transparant.
I am creating a instruction manual that will be printed.  My main intent is to put a bitmap image over a colored background in Inkscape.  I am using Inkscape to put everything together before exporting to PDF to send to the printers.
Below are the steps I have used to produce my instruction manual:

Cutout an image using GIMP (using select by color tool to select
white background, use mask to hide background, cropped image to
content).
Export cutout image as PNG in GIMP
Import PNG into Inkscape and place over color rectangle shape
Export artwork as PDF (as printers need this format)
Print PDF using a laser printer as a sample

When I print the exported PDF, I see a very faint background around the cutout where I expect it to be empty.  I cannot see this background when I view the document in Inkscape or the PDF file.
How can I resolve this issue?
Note: I believe I can fix this issue by making the colored background white but I wanted it colored for design purposes.


You don't need transparency if you are going to print a PNG image. Just make the background is pure white #ffffff.  White areas are non-printing  There's no white ink in an consumer grade inkjet printers or colour laser printers. There's also no white ink in full colour CMYK printing either.

Why Inkscape? That sample image appears to be entirely raster.

@Scott - I suspect the OP is using Inkscape to do layout, same as you can with Illustrator/Affinity Designer, for example placing a raster diagram and adding details, labels, arrows, etc.  However without being able to inspect the actual PNG, I don't know if this can be answered.  I also suspect the OP mentioning that they used GIMP's "color to alpha" might be part of the issue here, but that's just a guess.

To the OP, rather than using GIMP to remove the background, then it might be better to use a clipping mask in Inkscape.  This would mean drawing around the raster image with the Pen Tool, and selecting the raster image and the path, and doing Object > Clip > Set Clip.

@BillyKerr The instructions provided by the manufacturer already had clipping and masks in the PDF to get that image dimension smaller.  The original instructions had a white background.  It's only when I added the color background that the edges of the image would appear.  I thought using GIMP to "punch out" the image (ie remove background) would resolve the issue.

FYI - i editted my post for clarity

I wonder if there are issues with with how PDFs handle transparancies.  How to fix transparency issue in pdf output from Inkscape?

Was the PDF actually made in some other software originally? That may be the issue. The question you linked to is very old.  Inkscape does support transparency in PNGs inside a PDF.  I just tested it, all seems to be working.

The PDF was created from scratch using Inkscape.  I only re-used the images from the manufacturer.  I do have a hunch that there might be some issues with the images but I reprocessed them in GIMP.  Maybe i should try using a different image editor

Actually I tried it with GIMP.  It still looks OK. No issue.  Perhaps it's how you are removing the background that is the problem.  There have been issues with Colour to Alpha in the past. Why not just use a layer mask. Keep it simple.

I started off using a layer mask which did not work.  Then I started to explore other options that led me to the color to alpha method.  I also tried deleting the contents of the background with no luck.

Flatten the two raster images first.
A PDF is an export format, sometimes some bitmaps are rasterized over other elements, but this rasterization could not be optimal, so the best option is for you to control it.

The image is a png and the other layer is a Inkscape shape.  Since this document is going to be printed, I think most things should in vector format.

As you suggested, I changed the background shape in Inkscape to a bitmap using Make a Bitmap Copy (Under Edit) and it worked!  The transparancy part of the image does not show anymore over the colored background.  I think Inkscape exported PDF cannot handle transparancies well.  Ty for your recommendation!
